# Intersection of rank-local arrays with MPI

Tags: mpi, intersection

I wonder if there exist efficient MPI algorithms for finding intersection of rank-local arrays. Specifically, each rank holds a variable length array:

rank 0: a = [1,4,7,9]
rank 1: a = [2,3,7,8,10,12]
...

I need to check if there are duplicate values in these arrays (like the number 7 in the example above). The arrays are too large to be all moved to a single rank.

I googled around but found nothing.

Comment: Do a "circular bucket brigade": everyone passes their data down a ring of processes, and -- except for your own data -- note duplicates.